# Half orc fighter max starting HP

Tags: dnd-5e, hit-points, dnd-beyond

A non-playing friend of mine was looking around in the DnDBeyond website and created a (what I assume was a 1st lvl) character: half-orc with a STR of 19 and CON of 18. He showed me on his phone, but all I saw were the stats, and HP of 18/18. He said it was a fighter. Is there a way to start w/ 18 HP, given these parameters? My calculation was 14 HP.

Comment: Why do you assume this was a legitimate character? As in, no homebrew, no adding extra feats, etc

Comment: As @MivaScott says, the possibilities for an answer here are quite wide without seeing the character itself to find the error. Any answer will just be a guess without any support.

Comment: @MivaScott  I assumed it was legit because this person doesn't know anything about 5e, having last played 1e 30 yrs ago. I figured he just did what Beyond told him to do. I guess I need a closer look at the character. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't reading something wrong on figuring the HP bonuses.

Comment: Whether or not the character uses homebrew/is legitimate is irrelevant to the core of the question, which is "am I correct about my interpretation of the rules given these parameters?" Voted to leave open -from review.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Half Orcs don't have anything to increase HP (besides a con bonus), fighters have d10 hit die. 18 con gives you +4 con bonus, so that increases your hp by 4. So at level 1 you have 10 + 4 = 14 max hp.

If they were level 2, and yet to roll hp, they would have 18/18 hp. They could have also accidentally changed their hp manually or added feats.